# Could I bond java byte[] buffer to an InputStream and read for multiple times

Tags: java

Could I bond `readBuf` to DataInputStream,  I will read some bytes  to `readBuf`,  and I will read int and other data from DataInputStream which bond to `readBuf`. Can I do below  code?

```
byte[] readBuf = new byte[MAX_BYTE_SIZE ];
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(readBuf));
writeBytes( UartCmd[1] );
i_ReadLength = readBytes(readBuf);
uc_Index = dis.readInt();

writeBytes( i_WritedLength );
i_ReadLength = readBytes(readBuf);
uc_Index = dis.readInt();
```

thinks all your help.

Comment: I can't understand the question, sorry. Do you know someone who could help you write it in better english?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Why are you asking us, when the answer is right in front of you?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest java.nio.ByteBuffer

```
    ...
    uc_Index = ByteBuffer.wrap(readBuf).getInt();

    writeBytes( i_WritedLength );
    i_ReadLength = readBytes(readBuf);
    uc_Index = ByteBuffer.wrap(readBuf).getInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have "bonded" a byte[] buffer to an input stream with this line:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(readBuf));
```

That should work with `dis.readInt();` just fine.  Loop over it for as many int's as you expect to be in the buffer.

I can't tell you what's going to happen with `readBytes()` and `writeBytes()` since you haven't defined them.  The name `i_ReadLength` seems to mean something completely different than what I'd expect a method named `readBytes()` to return.  Your compiler won't care but us humans do.

If you're hoping to be able to look inside readBuf and tell how many int's have been added to it you're likely going to be disappointed.  A byte array of int's is not going to be null terminated like a string would be.  You MUST keep track of how much of the readBuf has been initialized with integers somewhere or you will end up reading garbage (data that was never written and could have any value).

What you could do is make the first int in the byte array the count of all the other int's in the array.  Once you read that you know how many times to loop.  Make sure to set it to the correct value when you write it.  Also don't write in to many int's and overflow the byte array.  Remember byte's and int's are different sizes.

If that's what you've done don't reinvent the wheel.  Do it like this:

```
byte[] readBuf = getSizePrefixedByteArrayOfInts();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(readBuf));
//writeBytes( UartCmd[1] ); //Seriously, I've no idea what this does

int i_ReadLength = dis.readInt();
int[] readInts = new int[i_ReadLength];

for(int i = 0; i < i_ReadLength; i++) {
    readInts[i] = dis.readInt();
}
```

Critical to understand here is that this code expects the length counter itself to NOT be counted.  If the counter is the only int initialized in the buffer then it's value should be zero.  So here's test some code that does that:

```
private byte[] getSizePrefixedByteArrayOfInts() {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
  DataOutputStream dos = null;
  int[] buf = {65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71};

  try{
     // create byte array output stream
     baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     // create data output stream
     dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);

     // write number of other ints in array
     dos.write(buf.length); 

     // write to the stream from integer array
     for(int i: buf)
     {
        dos.write(i);
     }

     // flushes bytes to underlying output stream
     dos.flush();

     return baos.toByteArray();

  }catch(Exception e){
     // if any error occurs
     e.printStackTrace();
  }finally{

     // releases all system resources from the streams
     if(baos!=null)
        baos.close();
     if(dos!=null)
        dos.close();
  }
}
```

My thanks to [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/dataoutputstream_write.htm) for the bulk of getSizePrefixedByteArrayOfInts() code.